# Make PyCrust use Python 3

Tags: linux, python, ide, python3

I make successfully python 3.2.3 by opening it through terminal, I make it by

```
alias python="python3"
```

[image]

But when I open the PyCrust IDE, it opens up with Python 2.7.3, not 3.2.3.
[image]

How can I make 3.2.3 as default? Is there any problem if I make it default? As far as I know maybe packages are run with 2.7.3 version of python. If I change default version then is it going well for my OS?

Comment: How you installed python? What's your distro? Try to be more specific. In many distribution you can select what IDE you want to install and use. Changing the default version of idle won't do anything to your OS. After all, you can change these version whenever you want.

Comment: The only [docs I found for PyCrust](http://wxpython.org/py.php) are very short and don't mention this.  My guess is it just runs `python`.  But other programs don't see your aliases.  Your alias just makes it so when *you* type `python`, it runs `python3`.  If you need to use Python 3, I'd suggest looking for a different IDE, such as PyCharm or PyDev.